# Why is my map zoomed in so ragged compared to what I actually drawed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, zoom, topojson

So overall my map looks the same like what I draw in QGIS. The issue is that when I **zoom** in, in that case **54x** then you can see **ragged lines**.

QGIS
[image]

Browser
[image]

That is not what I need. I need **high details** also by **zooming in**. So how can I improve that.

One thing I could do is simplyfying the topojson file. But that's not a solution because I need that high quality lines because my map is often used by zooming in.

Also I could smooth the lines a bit. But already tested and still looking bad.

So how can I also by zooming in show max details. How can I tell QGIS to give more details. Or is it something of the projection? I'm using this projection: +proj=eqc +a=190493.11 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +rf=800 +units=m +no_defs. But I don't think that I can change it without loosing all right?

Comment: What kind of data (vector or raster) do you use, and how do you display the QGIS output in your browser?

Comment: Well the picture from QGIS is a TIF picture. And there I draw a polygon on. Then I export as geojson all the different layers. And finally with topojson merging als geojson's to one topojson. Then I show it with D3.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing I work with. Could the edges come from a limited precision of your topojson coordinates, compared to those of QGIS layers?

Comment: I don't know, what should I check out? I mean the projection I have written in the question. And I just read it and scale it a bit. But even if I change the scalling it is still pixelated. =(

Comment: Your data should be in meters, but with how many decimals behind the comma? The geojson format can be opened with any text editor to check that. In QGIS, you can measure the distance between two vertices in map untis. BTW your ellipsoid is rather small. Are you working on another planet?

Comment: Actually I started my project with some issues. Then I found this projection and didn't ask anything about it anymore. So this projection is pretty much random and can be changed without any problems. But isn't the issue that now chaging the projection is killing my data?

Comment: This is something from one geojson. What cann you tell from this: { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": null, "eventname": null, "size": null }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 0.040829062166367, -0.019982783052928 ], ...

Comment: These coordinates are rather small, and if D3 rounds them thinking they are meters, you get the ragged look when zooming in.

Comment: Well I was looking on the path and id does not change. So you mean the rouding is happening in the background right? And how can I change it from meter to whatever is needed. Just with changing the projection?

Comment: To get it right, you can look at the extent of the layer in Properties, metadata tab, and consider what extent you really want. Then you can assign a different projection to the data with kilometers as units. But it might be worth to wait for QGIS 2.8 for that. Older versions of QGIS handle only meters and feet correctly.

Comment: In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 0.0263196,-0.0181259 : xMax,yMax 0.0464427,-0.00810942
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

Comment: But where can I change these values. I mean I have a backup I can test anything, but that projection changing is really messy.

Comment: Here you have a CRS with degrees as units (longlat) and an ellipsoid that makes sense. You can not simply call it meters on a half-sized planet if you hand it over to D3. Instead, you have to use Save as to another file and a different projection with meters as units. Then you get reasonable coordinates in meters.

Comment: And which projection would it be then? Mhh well I have 20 layers and for each one I would now have to save as new layer and test it. Wow that would be huge. Or is there a way to minimize the points of polygons. I mean I did it with many details and that's why it looks so damn ugly now. So Instead of drawing the polygons now again and deleting the old ones. Is there a way to just reduce the points?

Comment: Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Simplify Geometries might help.

Comment: Mhh tested with 0,0000 what reduced from 130 to 120. That's too less. But the only next step is 0,0001. But here is goes down to 5 points =/ So does not work for me or let's say too less and too much

Comment: Maybe you should reproject to meters first, then simplify.

Comment: Mhh I resolved it with some CSS mechanics. It's not the best but the easiest right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AndreJ described, I should resave all the layers to a better projection or whatever. But I don't know if this is resolving my issue as I wish. So I now use CSS strokes with some round lines like this:

```
 fill: #188;
 fill-opacity: 0.7;
 stroke-width: 0.3px;
 stroke: #188;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 stroke-miterlimit: 2;
```

[image]

Yeah not the best or the correct lines but at least not ragged anymore.